# Ubuntu Server/Samba

Tags: server, samba, users, groups

I've installed Ubuntu Server and added Samba to use as a very basic file server with a few different users with their own accounts. Should I create the users and the groups in Ubuntu or in Samba, or perhaps in both? Most guides I've came across seem to take that for granted...

Comment: Have you checked https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba, the sections `Configuring Samba Servers` and `Configuring Samba Clients`? Also https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/ contains plenty of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users are in the local /etc/passwd Samba just uses those users ,means samba uses local `/etc/passwd` users to grant access to resources, in the `/etc/samba/smbpasswd` file is just the mapping of those users and those user's windows compatable password hashes. So create users and groups in ubuntu and also add those users password to the `/etc/samba/smbpasswd` file as windows compatable hashes using the command

```
Smbpasswd -a username
```